# Unable to include font folder in java application

Tags: java, css, tomcat, web-deployment

I am facing a weird problem and I am stuck at the moment. I have a java application running in tomcat on my local machine. Recent requirement was to include a new font for the app. I downloaded the font and put in under a folder lookandfeel where my style.css is.

Current Folder structure

[image]

in my style.css I am importing the font using the following code

```
@import url("/font/stylesheet.css");
html {font-family: "Clarimo UD PE", Helvetica, Sans-Serif;}
```

But when I run my code it still uses 'Helvetica' and my folder structure is this

[image]

Somehow it is not deploying the font folder. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your whole file tree but by the looks of things the directory called "lookandfeel" is inside the root directory.

Your import URL is looking for a directory called font which is a child of the root directory. I think you meant to use "font/stylesheet.css" or "/lookandfeel/font/stylesheet.css"

Comment: "font/stylesheet.css" worked. I didn't know one slash could create so much trouble for me. Thanks heaps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@import url("../font/stylesheet.css");
html {font-family: "Clarimo UD PE", Helvetica, Sans-Serif;}
```

It is checking for the `font` folder inside look and feel directory.